# Accessing nested parameters in Symfony ParameterBag

Tags: symfony, request

Have a request that looks like this

```
ParameterBag {#362 ▼
  #parameters: array:1 [▼
    "form" => array:5 [▼
      "titre" => "new b"
      "prix" => "4444"
      "slug" => "with-different-slug"
      "publier" => "unpub"
      "Modifier" => ""
    ]
  ]
}
```

How can I use the 
$post = Request::createFromGlobals();
$post->request->has() on those nested properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ParameterBag's `has` function does not support deep check. It is just an `array_key_exists` call.

You could use `get` with `$deep` parameter set to `true`.

E.g.:

```
$post = Request::createFromGlobals();
$post->request->get('form[titre]', null, true);
```

It will return `null` (the second parameter), if the value does not exist.

EDIT:

This function however deprecated in 2.8.

`Using paths to find deeper items in get is deprecated since version 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0. Filter the returned value in your own code instead.`

Comment: `Note: Finding deep items is deprecated since version 2.8, to be removed in 3.0.`